# React - Deleting from middle of list removes last element instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a simple practice app in React. I have four components: a main component that stores users as objects in an array, a userView component that renders each user's info, a userList component that renders all userViews, and a addUser component that adds a new user to the main component on submit. Adding and editing items in the list works correctly. However, I'm running into an issue with delete. Each list item has its own delete button that should delete that element, but no matter which delete button is used, the last element in the list is deleted. I'm deleting from the array containing the users in Main using splice, and I've checked that splice is being passed the correct index when a delete button is pressed.

I think this has something to do with keys on the components when the virtual DOM rerenders, but I've tried adding keys with a few different methods (component.id, global counter variable, index in the array) and still had no luck. Here are the relevant pieces of code (I've left as much out as possible for brevity):

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      allUsers: []
    }
  },
  removeUser: function(index){
    console.log('index to remove at: ', index); //Gives correct index
    var newUsersArray = this.state.allUsers.slice();
    newUsersArray.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      allUsers: newUsersArray
    });
  },
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <AddUser addNew={this.addUser} index={this.state.allUsers.length} />
        <UserList users={this.state.allUsers} edit={this.editUser} remove={this.removeUser} />
      </div>
  )
  }
})

  var UserList = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      var users = this.props.users;
      var edit = this.props.edit;
      var remove = this.props.remove;
      return (
        <div>
        {users.map(function(user){
          return <UserView userName={user.name} userRoles={user.roles} editUser={edit} remove={remove} key={user.id} index={user.index}/>
    })}
       </div>
      );
    }
});

var UserView = React.createClass({
  handleDelete: function(){
    this.props.remove(this.props.index);
});
```

I left out quite a bit, here's all my React code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dpdbv731/. Basically, when a userView component is clicked, it calls the removeUser function on Main with the index of that component as the parameter. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The key on *UserView* is undefined - there is no *id* field on *user*. This causes React to fall back to using the array index as the key. Now, when you remove item 0 in a 2 element list, there will be one component left, which has the key "0". During reconciliation, React will associate the remaining element passed as props with the *component that previously had key "0"*. In other words, the correct array element is passed, but it is associated with the wrong component, and since this component contains some state, it looks like wrong item is removed. Since the index is unique per user in your example, you can remedy this problem by adding key={user.index} to *UserView*.