# Why is removing an item from a list with the key as index working as expected?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in which you can add or remove an option item. When I remove an option item, it is simply removed from an `options` list stored in state using the `index` value.

I would have thought that because I am using an `index` as the key, whenever I deleted an option item, the last element would incorrectly be removed however it seems to be working as expected.

```
   displayedOptions = options.map((option, optionIndex) => (
      <DropdownOption
        option={option}
        onRemoveOption={() => onRemoveOption(optionIndex)}
        onChange={onChangeOption(optionIndex)}
        key={optionIndex}
      />
    ));
```

```
  const onRemoveOption = (taskIndex: number) => (optionIndex: number) => {
    const newTaskFields = [...taskFields];
    newTaskFields[taskIndex].options = newTaskFields[taskIndex].options.filter(
      (_option, index) => {
        return optionIndex !== index;
      }
    );
    setTaskFields(newTaskFields);
  };
```

Are there any risks to doing it this way?
Would anyone know why this is working as expected?

I thought the behaviour in my app would have been similar to what was reported here: [React - Deleting from middle of list removes last element instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658604/react-deleting-from-middle-of-list-removes-last-element-instead)

That is, if I had an list that used indexes as keys containing the following values:

```
[a, b, c]
```

and I removed index 0 ('a'), I thought the diff would have been between:

```
Original:
[0:a, 1:b, 2:c]
and
Updated:
[0:b, 1:c]
```

In this case, React would see that keys `0` and `1` still exist and would continue to render `a` and `b` as it would assume these haven't changed. This would result in `c` disappearing (not `a`).

Thank you.

Comment: Well, presumably if deleting by index the delete handler correctly filters the options by elements *not* at that index then I would expect it to work as intended. We can't see your `onRemoveOption` code though. Is your question really, "My code works and I don't know why?"

Comment: @DrewReese I have included the `onRemoveOption`. Yes, that is essentially my question.

Comment: Yup, you create a shallow copy of state, mutate it (delete element matched by index) and update state. Looks to be mostly in order as I would expect it to be. Missing is the shallow copy of `newTaskFields[taskIndex]` first, but I guess that isn't causing issue for you; it's a potential for state mutation.

Answer (score 1):

Your `onRemoveOption` is partially correct. You *should* shallowly copy *all* elements of the array/object you intend to update (mutate/remove/etc...).

Your `onRemoveOption` handler would then become something like:

```
const onRemoveOption = (taskIndex: number) => (optionIndex: number) => {
  setTaskFields((tasks) =>
    tasks.map((task, index) =>
      index === taskIndex
        ? {
            ...task,
            options: task.options.filter((_, index) => index !== optionIndex)
          }
        : task
    )
  );
};
```

- Uses a functional state update
- Maps the tasks to a new array object
- If the task index matches the one you need to delete an option from, shallow copy to new object and update the `options` property, otherwise return the task object
- If deleting an option, filter the options by index

Comment: Thanks Drew, but did you mean to say you should shallowly copy all the elements of the array/object we do not intend to update? As you are simply returning the `task` that we are not updating.

Comment: I have also updated my question to explain what I'm wondering regarding the indexes

Comment: @Bleh Nope, you are updating an element in the array, so you need to shallowly copy all the elements into a new array, and since you are updating the options property of a specific element, then shallowly copy the properties into a new object and update the options property. The elements that don't have their options updated are simply passed to the new array. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-removing-an-item-from-a-list-with-the-key-as-index-working-as-expected-8zi6m?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Issue will raise while implementing sorting and Removing based on map index.

for example

let Options = [d,a,e,y];

right now Options and index looks like this way.

d 0
a 1
e 2
y 3

Removing item always apply changes from last item. Because you are not passing unique key to the item. Read diff algorithm.

But if you implement sorting and removing  - it will failed in removing specific element

after sorting index will change
a 0
d 1
e 2
y 3

You can send option name instead of index.

Comment: Thanks Vsquare but why am I not seeing the last item disappear even though I am using indexes? I have updated my question with some details at the end